# Problem with continue in While Loop within Try/Catch in C# (2.0)

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0, try-catch

**Update2**
okay, i was able to get it to work, but i think there is a problem having
two different datareaders whiles within another. after moving it out
of the outer while in a method it works. The Exception from the 1st update was because i didn't closed the reader, so it opened too many tables an JET crashed on the 2048 open tables. So but i'm not very pleased with the result, but at least the data comes out.

I think for MDB purposes in C# it's maybe better to use the good old ADODB COM Wrapper which has been proven to do it's job.

Thanks to all your comments.

**Update**
After I moved it into a method i get now this exception:

```
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at getMoney(String card, String field)Unspecified errorMicrosoft JET Database Engine
```

When I try to use in my ASPX Webpage in the Code Behind this:

```
try
{                   
    while()
    {
        ...
        db.Open();
        readDataMoney = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE card = '" + customer.card + "';", db).ExecuteReader();
        while (readDataMoney.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                if (!readDataMoney.IsDBNull(readDataMoney.GetOrdinal("Credit")))
                {
                    customer.credit = Convert.ToDouble(readDataMoney[readDataMoney.GetOrdinal("Credit")]);
                }
                if (!readDataMoney.IsDBNull(readDataMoney.GetOrdinal("Bonus")))
                {
                    customer.bonus = Convert.ToDouble(readDataMoney[readDataMoney.GetOrdinal("Bonus")]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Connector.writeLog("Money: " + ex.StackTrace + "" + ex.Message + "" + ex.Source);
                customer.credit = 0.0;
                customer.credit = 0.0;
                continue;
            }
            finally { }
        }
        readDataMoney.Close();
        db.Close();
        ...
    }
}
catch
{
    continue;
}
```

The whole page hangs if there is a problem when the read from db isn't working. 
I tried to check for !isNull, but same problem.
I have a lots of differend MDB Files to process, which are readonly (can't repair/compact)
and some or others not. Same Design/Layout of Tables. With good old ASP Classic 3.0
all of them are processing with the "On Resume Next". I know I know. But that's how it is.
Can't change the source. So the basic question:

So is there any way to tell .NET to continue the loop whatever happens within the 
try loop if there is any exception?

After a lots of wating time i get this exceptions:

```
    at System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.IDBInitializeInitialize.Invoke(IntPtr pThis)
   at System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper.InitializeAndCreateSession(OleDbConnectionString constr, SessionWrapper& sessionWrapper)   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at GetCustomer(String card)Thread was being aborted.System.Data
```

and

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt16(IntPtr ptr, Int32 ofs) 
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbBuffer.ReadInt16(Int32 offset) 
System.Data.OleDb.ColumnBinding.Value_I2() 
System.Data.OleDb.ColumnBinding.Value() 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GetValue(Int32 ordinal) 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.get_Item(Int32 index) 
Thread was terminated.mscorlib
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think if there is a problem when reading the database file you won't be able to continue the inner while loop. But I'm not sure exactly what is your question. Why do you have two try-catch blocks?

Comment: the second try/catch was just a try but it doesnt make any difference if its there or not. my first guess was also about the too loop, that may continue applies to the outer while so it stucks on the inner one, but this is would be a design error of .net, or? i can't be to stuck in a loop without be able to continue on a exception.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's catching an exception on the last record in the file and then, because end-of-file has already been reached, it just keeps throwing an exception and `continue`ing, over and over again.

I suspect that you *don't* need two continue statements, but only one (the inside one).

You should rewrite this in a way that *doesn't require an exception to control the program flow.*

Comment: oh, sounds good, but how to avoid or handle it.
it's only one or none. card id is unique.

Comment: Check reader.IsEof, or other similar property that returs if the end of file was reached.

Comment: Try removing both `continue` statements and the outside `try/catch`, and see what happens.

Comment: @Carlos: I think he's already doing that with the `while (readDataMoney.Read())`.

Comment: @Robert you are right, I was not sure if it the read was doing that or not, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Robert: I changed code and moved try/catch out of the while. But same result.

System.Data.Common.SafeNativeMethods.SetErrorInfo(Int32 dwReserved, IntPtr pIErrorInfo)

Strange thing still to me is. Why is it working on some db's and some not. 
I just want .NET to continue the loop and not to terminate the thread.

The try should be better within the loop, otherwise it's if i want to have more exception logic
on seperate fields it won't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that inside the `catch` block you do this:

```
Connector.writeLog(...
```

What class is `Connector`, and what does it do inside `writeLog`?  Does it attempt to write the error information to a table in a database, or does it write to a file or the event log or something else?

Also, this is probably a typo, but in your code sample you close a different connection (`vsiDB`) than the one you open (`db`).

Comment: Connector writeLog does only write a txt file, the db thing is a copy and paste mistake, connection is fine.